# How can I iterate tests with different values in robot framework with python

Tags: python, automation, robotframework

I need to iterate whole test suit depending on the list passed through command line.

```
Suite Setup  Data Set Up  ABC.json  ${A}  ${B}  sanity  


Default Tags  sanity


*** Variables ***
@{list}  set variable  

*** Test Cases ***

test_001_ABC_test_one

    Run ABC one

test_002_ABC_test_two

    Run ABC two

test_003_ABC_test_three

    Run ABC three

test_004_ABC_test_four

    Run ABC four

test_005_ABC_test_five

    Run ABC five
```

I want this 5 tests should iterate for the number of items present in the @{List} and everytime it should pass that item of the list to the test case.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a case of Data Driven Test. In Robot Framework we use Templates keywords. See the documentation [here](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-templates).

Comment: But my List size is not going to be fixed. So  I need to loop through the list checking for the next item present and accordingly pass the value to the test case.

Comment: use robotframework-datadriver .. with it, you can have any size of dataset and run the tests against it one by one ..